# Display email, name from created session on a new page?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I believe I have created A very simple login form of some kind. How do  I go about of displaying the name and email on another page? That's even if I am creating a session correctly.

```php
<?php
    session_start();

    include('./includes/mysql_connect.php');

    $email = ($_POST['email']);;
    $password = ($_POST['password']);

    $match = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'";

    $qry = mysql_query($match);

    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($qry);

    if($num_rows <=0 ){
        echo "Sorry there is no email";
        exit;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['user']=$_POST['email'];
        header("location:logged.php");
    }
?>
```

`Create table` statement:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply print the session values in logged.php

```
echo $_SESSION['user'];
```

Comment: Undefined variable: _SESSION

Comment: You need to start sessions by writing `session_start();` And I assume that error is actually `$_SESSION`, not _SESSION.

Comment: So any page I want the session to be accessible I must begin with session_start() ?

Comment: That's how you start sessions. If you're going to do session related work in your script, you need to start sessions by calling `session_start` once.

Answer (score 0):

ITS EASY

```
 <?php
     session_start();
     echo $_SESSION['user'];
 ?>
```

Comment: Note that `$_REQUEST` does **NOT** contain the `$_SESSION` variables, but only the `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE` variables.

Answer (score 0):

You've got `$_SESSION['user']`

Just start sessions at the beginning of your 2nd php file and you can use `$_SESSION['user']`

Now you want to do it with your name as well, (since `$_SESSION['user']`=Email).
Just do the same but instead of `'user'` use something like `'name'`